# Жизненный цикл Activity. Сохранение состояния виджета

Tags: android, activity, button, виджет, activity-life-cycle

"Реализация по умолчанию `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` приказывает всем представлениям `Activity` сохранить свое состояние в данных объекта `Bundle` —
структуры, связывающей строковые ключи со значениями из ограниченного набора типов" - цитата из книги о жизненном цикле `Activity`.
Блокирую кнопку (setEnabled(false)), поворачиваю экран, кнопка - разблокирована. Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В офф.документации [сказано](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru), что во первых, по дефолту сохраняются только состояния виджетов, которые имеют ID (назначено `android:id`), а во вторых, далеко не полное состояние сохраняется по умолчанию, ведь каждый виджет имеет десятки параметров и все их сохранить просто нереально. В частности сказано, что сохраняется текст, введенный в `EditText`, позиция в списке `ListView`, отметка `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` и тому подобные основные параметры.

Видимо параметр "блокировки виджета" в список основных параметров не входит и вам нужно позаботится о сохранении состояния этого параметра самостоятельно, переопределив методы `onSaveInstanceState()`\ `onRestoreInstanceState()`